# Cannot create redis cache on azure: Redis Management Client error

Tags: azure, ansible, redis-cache

I am trying to create a simple redis cache on azure via ansible.
Here's my code:

```
- name: Create an Azure Cache for Redis
  azure_rm_rediscache:
  resource_group: 'dev-rg
  name: 'dev-cache'
  sku:
   name: basic
   size: C1
```

But, I'm having this error:
**TypeError: RedisManagementClient.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'credential'**

I tried changing the **azure-mgmt-redis** version that was initially **5.0.0** but always the same error.

Comment: Please make sure you are using the latest versions of 1) ansible(-core) 2) the azure collection 3) the required python dependencies before going on with this question.

Comment: I have verified that, all of the packages are with the latest versions.

Comment: You have verified that on the target server that executes the module and for the target python version ansible is using on that server?

Comment: Yes, I'm executing the task on localhost.

Comment: localhost as controler can run a different python than localhost as a target. You want to have everything up-to-date in the target python. This is a common misunderstanding in ansible hence why I'm extra cautious.